# Android MVVM/Repository how to force LiveData to update from repository?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, repository-pattern, android-livedata

here is my problem:

i have used MVVM/Repository design pattern like this:

Activity -(Observes)-> ViewModel's LiveData -> Repository -> WebService API (GET Resource)

i have another calls for **UPDATING** *Resource* to WebService.

Problem:

**after changing resource on the server. how i can make the *Resource* livedata to update itself with new servers data**

i want to force it fetch data from server again because some other data may have been changed.
and i dont want to use local database (Room) and change it because my server data might be changed. and they need to fetch each time.

The Only solution passed my Mind was to create a Livedata Source (as dataVersion) to it.
and increment it after every update like this (pseudo code):

```
dataVersion = new MutableLiveData();
dataVersion.setValue(0);
// my repository get method hasnt anything to do with the dataVersion.
myData = Transformation.switchmap(dataVersion, versionNum -> { WebServiceRepo.getList() });
```

and how dataVersion should get updated in ViewModel.

Comment: Why are you so against local db? The only thing you have to do is update it every time when server's data changes. As I understood you want and know how to send signal from server to your app when data changes (cloud message or something else). Getting this message you can call your WebServiceAPI, update your local DB and after that your ViewModel can get actual data (that would be data from local db of course) without any difficulties with LiveData help. As a bonus you app can live without internet.

Comment: my usecase is a shopping cart which most of the goods has subside and discount and there will be a lot of customer at the good existence announcement, so The shopping cart entities data for each user has been kept with an short-timed cache-server in the server. and the application shopping cart  should fetch data on each reload to see if items has been revoked from the cart or not. (customers only have like 5 minutes to buy Goods before their shopping cart item disappears). because of this i wont keep this data in local db.

Comment: but i made it using cache Busting mechanism and versioning every updated list.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend `MutableLiveData` to give it manual fetch functionality.

```
public class RefreshLiveData<T> extends MutableLiveData<T> {
    public interface RefreshAction<T> {
        private interface Callback<T> {
             void onDataLoaded(T t);
        }

        void loadData(Callback<T> callback);
    }

    private final RefreshAction<T> refreshAction;
    private final Callback<T> callback = new RefreshAction.Callback<T>() {
          @Override
          public void onDataLoaded(T t) {
               postValue(t);
          }
    };

    public RefreshLiveData(RefreshAction<T> refreshAction) {
        this.refreshAction = refreshAction;
    }

    public final void refresh() {
        refreshAction.loadData(callback);
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
public class YourViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private RefreshLiveData<List<Project>> refreshLiveData;

    private final GithubRepository githubRepository;
    private final SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle;

    public YourViewModel(GithubRepository githubRepository, SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle) {
         this.githubRepository = githubRepository;
         this.savedStateHandle = savedStateHandle;

         refreshLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(savedStateHandle.getLiveData("userId", ""), (userId) -> {
             githubRepository.getProjectList(userId);
         });
    }

    public void refreshData() {
        refreshLiveData.refresh();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Project>> getProjects() {
        return refreshLiveData;
    }
}
```

And then repository can do:

```
public RefreshLiveData<List<Project>> getProjectList(String userId) {
    final RefreshLiveData<List<Project>> liveData = new RefreshLiveData<>((callback) -> {
         githubService.getProjectList(userId).enqueue(new Callback<List<Project>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Project>> call, Response<List<Project>> response) {
                callback.onDataLoaded(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Project>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
         });
    });

    return liveData;
}
```